# magento community 1.7.0.2 product collection sort does not work

Tags: php, magento, sorting

I am having a problem with sort order in magento.

```
    $productPriceCollection = $products2->addAttributeToSort('mb_rank', 'DESC')->setPageSize("3")->addStoreFilter()->load();
    $priceOrderCollection = $productPriceCollection->setOrder('price', 'ASC')->load();
```

What I am trying to do here is getting the first 3 products which has the highest mb_rank and then sorting only that three by price ascending and loading that list as the final list that I use for the rest of the process.

But I am always getting the order as price Descending.

I have already tried

```
    $priceOrderCollection = $productPriceCollection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'ASC')->load();
```

No difference.

What am I doing wrong here?

Best

Comment: what type is your attribute (text, select, int) ?

Comment: price field type is price.

Comment: I was talking about `mb_rank`

Comment: mb_rank is textfield. integer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow found half of the solution, First of all if you use textfield, Magento will not sort it correctly, you need to use price as field type to sort your integer values correctly. Otherwise it will be counted as a string value.

Adding the second sort for the first three results is still not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the comments. I just realized that the attribute type is not important in your case.
The problem is that you are using `->load` for your collection.
Once you load your collection you cannot modify the order or filters on it.
Try it like this.

```
$productPriceCollection = $products2->addAttributeToSort('mb_rank', 'DESC')
    ->setPageSize("3")
    ->addStoreFilter()
    ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'ASC')
    ->load();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try it in 5mins and let you know about the result.

Comment: Unfortunatelly only the price sort worked this time and mb_rank sort does not have any affects.

Comment: Make sure you rebuilt your indexes.

Comment: I did it several times and did it once again but it did not change anything on the result list.

Comment: Sorry I wrote the wrong attribute on comment. mb_rank is working still but price sort did not work. What must be the field settings to be able to sort by that field ?

Comment: I have no idea. It should work in my opinion if you don't call load before settings a sort order